# What could be the cause of these window cracks in a London Victorian house?

Tags: windows, crack

The crack I am interested in is this (bottom of the window):

[image]

To give some context, the house has some other cracks on the rendering plint:

[image]

[image]

[image]

There also seems to be some sagging of the brickwork at the front:

[image]

Comment: You've answered your own question. The sagging brickwork you've noted in your last picture is what's causing the cracks elsewhere.

Comment: Regarding the 'sagging brickwork' - how do you know it hasn't always been like that? Bricklaying is rarely a precision trade.

Comment: @NMF - "always been like that" is a bit of a stretch when it comes to Victorian period architecture - Victoria reigned from 1837 to 1901 - making the house anything between 120 & 185 years old, give or take. This looks late Victorian though, so a mere century or so,

Comment: @Tetsujin - I've no idea what your point is! The house could have been built with imperfectly straight and/or unlevel courses however old it is - and if it was, then nothing has changed. NB I'm not referring to the localised cracking/movement - that is obviously a defect, though also could be historic.

Comment: @NMF - sorry, didn't realise you meant only the last picture. tbh, that might not be as bad as it looks from the photo. To get a true representation you'd need to take the photo from parallel, with a good rectilinear lens [which excludes any phone camera].

Answer (score 4):

London is built on clay. Everything sags.
You'll need a surveyor to accurately measure it & put movement marker clips on to test how far it moves per year, then weigh up whether or not it's going to be necessary/worthwhile to underpin it.
I have a very similar-looking property built in a terrace with an L-shape plan & the farthest corner of the L has moved maybe as much as 3" over a century. I've had it looked at - it's not going anywhere fast, though eventually I'll have to underpin it… which is not cheap.

You get additional problems with modern 'plonk-in' double-glazing, in that you have removed any additional support originally provided by the big, solid old wooden frames. You can even see additional slippage where the replacement wooden window was put into what used to be a bigger space. They've bricked above & below, which is standing up well, but the decorative arch has cracked above it.

It's hard to tell whether the cement render which has cracked is original or a later remedial patch. Check the other houses down the street to see if they're all identical, for clues.

Comment: When foundations are underpinned in London how far down do the pins go to reach firmer soil or rock?

Comment: Well, most of London except for the few hills - notable in that there are so few they named all of them. [Can you tell I come from a county with real hills;) is essentially an alluvial plain on a chalk basin. London clay is considered a 'bedrock' in the broadest terms. idk all figures, but for instance Westminster the chalk is 70m down. Having watched the proceedings next door, what they actually do is make a bigger, concrete 'raft' that the building sits on. I don't think modern buildings suffer from this, just because the foundations are considerably more substantial than 100 years ago.

Comment: I found this - https://www.lnhs.org.uk/index.php/articles-british/249-geology-of-london Brief enough to not cause migraine ;)